# How to assign label name of cbutton to be $data?

Tags: php, yii, cbuttoncolumn

How can i get $data->user->name to be label name of button.

```
'label' => $data->user->name
```

in :

```
array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        'template'=>'{Preview}',
        'buttons'=>array(
            'Preview'=>array(
                'label'=>'Details',
                'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("/administration/order/getBillingInfo", array("id"=>$data->id))',
                'click'=>'window.billingInfo',

            ),
        ),
        'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:center;', 'class'=>'gButtons'),
    ),
```

This is my Widget:

```
<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'orders-grid',
    'ajaxUpdate'=>false,
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'grid'),
    'pager'=>array(
        'maxButtonCount'=>Yii::app()->params['maxButtonCount'],
    ),
```

How can i get `$data->user->name` to be label name of button.

Answer (score 0):

$data does not exist in that context

Try:

```
'label' => '$data->user->name'
```

Comment: That prints '$data->user->name', but thanks for the answer, i think i know what i need to do.

Answer (score 0):

`label` is supposed to be a fixed string, not an expression. You will have to extend [`CButtonColumn`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CButtonColumn) so it'll feature a `labelExpression` that gets evaluated. The [code for the `url` property](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/zii/widgets/grid/CButtonColumn.php#L335) should give you a fairly good idea.

Comment: DaSourcerer Thanks, I get it, label is for string, and thanks for the hint i'll try to do it with url prop. and if I do it i will update my "stupid" question  :)

Comment: 'i will update my "stupid" question :) ' -- Don't look at me. I haven't been the one who downvoted it :P

Comment: I didn't mean that is you :) I think it is stupid, because i didn't think enough and now i can't delete it :D cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try with double quotes:

```
'label' => "$data->user->name"
```

Comment: double quotes makes $data as variable, but not as property. It is wrong way